# linear algebra approach to discrete cosine transform

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

I understand that the discrete Fourier transform simply changes basis to the discrete Fourier basis, which is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for any shift-invariant linear operator on $\mathbb C^n$.  The discrete Fourier basis can be easily discovered by computing the eigenvectors of the shift operator $S:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$, which maps
$\begin{bmatrix} x_0 & x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}^T$ to
$\begin{bmatrix} x_{n-1} & x_0 & x_1 & \cdots & x_{n-2} \end{bmatrix}^T$.

Is there an analogous way understand the discrete cosine transform?  Does the discrete cosine basis diagonalize some particular class of linear operators (as the discrete Fourier basis diagonalizes any shift-invariant linear operator)?  Is there some simple and fundamental linear operator, analogous to $S$, which can be used to discover the discrete cosine basis?

How can I expand my understanding of the DFT to include the DCT?  How does DCT fit into the picture?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this paper by Gilbert Strang while searching for something related to the DCT: http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/papers/dct.pdf.

On page 3 it says: "The basis vectors of cosines are actually eigenvectors of symmetric second-difference matrices." Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually simple:
To the function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,L)$, attach the function $g(x)=f(-x)$ defined on $[-L,0)$.  The resulting composite function $h(x)$ is even ($h(x) = h(-x)$) on the interval $[-L,L)$, therefore its Fourier series has cosines only.  This captures the DCT of $f(x)$.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the Fourier cosine series, but I was asking about the discrete cosine transform described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform